# Push Down body onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that includes jQuery. When the site loads, I'm checking a cookie to see if the user has or has not accepted a cookie policy. If the user has not previously accepted the cookie policy, I want to show them a prompt at the top of the screen. I want to push the rest of the content down. For that reason, I'm trying this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isAccepted = false;
  if (isAccepted !== 'true') {
    var notice = '<div><div id="myNotice" class="container" style="height:0px;">' +
      'This site uses cookies. ' +
      'Are you ok with this?' +
      '<button id="acceptButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Accept</button>' +
      '</div></div>';

    $('body').prepend(notice);
    $('#myNotice').animate({
      height: 100
    }, 200);

    $('#acceptButton').on('click', function() {
      $('#cookieNotice').animate({
        height: 0
      }, 300);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</div>
```

My problem is, the notice shows at the top no matter what. It doesn't slide down, pushing "Hello" down, when the page loads. I'm not sure why. What am I missing?

Comment: Your code snippet works fine.  Do you have additional css on your page (eg fixed position header)?

Comment: Your code starts off by setting `isAccepted` to `false` and then immediately tests that against the *string* `true`. It will always be `false` because you just set it to `false` on the previous line. You need to test for the cookie and set `isAccepted` based on what you find.

Comment: Also, `isAccepted !== 'true'` is really just `!isAccepted`

Comment: do you want the page to move after the entire page has been loaded or after the DOM content is finished loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your condition is not working, just use

```
if(!isAccepted){
```

because as stated **[HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)**, the `!==` or `===` operator compares the **value AND type**. You were trying to compare a string with a boolean, so it was definitely not working.

Also, you have to change `#cookieNotice` into `#myNotice`, because `#cookieNotice` doesn't exist, so your button would never hide the notice.

In my snippet, I changed the style of your generated notice div `height = 0px;` to `display: none;` and used the existing jquery `.slideDown` and `.slideUp` to make your notice slide as you wished while giving a better readability (in my opinion).

Here is the full code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var isAccepted = false;
      if (!isAccepted) {
            var notice = '<div><div id="myNotice" class="container" style="display: none;">' +
                'This site uses cookies. ' +
                'Are you ok with this?' +
                '<button id="acceptButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Accept</button>' +
                '</div></div>'
            ;
    
            $('body').prepend(notice);
            $('#myNotice').slideDown(200);
    
            $('#acceptButton').on('click', function() {
                $('#myNotice').slideUp(300);
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <h1>
  Hello
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `#cookieNotice` to `#myNotice` and use `.slideUp(300)`

```
   $('#acceptButton').on('click', function() {
          $('#myNotice').slideUp(300);
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ms4au3vn/ with working example

Answer (score 0):

Try this to slideUp the notice when it's accepted.

```
$(document).on('click', '#acceptButton', function() {
   $('#myNotice').animate({
     height: 0
   }, 300);
});
```